# Understanding Keras/TF results variation on different architectures

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I've been running a [notebook](https://gist.github.com/EKami/33ec0172590ab9f2e3a6b757c9f9dcb4) that yields a model with good performance. It's about a Kaggle competition for which more details can be found [here](http://kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space).

When I run the same notebook on my AWS p2 instance, I consistently get worst results. When I run it on my macbook, I get terrible results. The original model has a score of 0.922, I roughly get 0.91 on my ec2 instance, and 0.7-0.8 on my macbook. I'm wondering what different settings can cause this. I've thought of:

- The seeds were different and there was some luck involved.
- We're probably not running the same version of different packages, so the code run is actually different
- We've different GPU/CPU settings. I don't have a good grasp on how this impact the training.

Given the huge difference I'm seeing on my macbook (even a 0.012 diff is actually quite large) my guess is that there's more going on than different seeding, or even slightly different version of packages (I'm quite up to date on my packages) I'm expecting the CPU/GPU architecture to have no impact except on speed, but I might be wrong.

### Relevant info:

#### Scoring

The model yields prediction probabilities that are converted to labels when the proba is higher than 0.2, and the model is scored with it's average [F2 score](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space#evaluation) on predictions.

#### Model

The model is a quite simple CNN: https://github.com/EKami/planet-amazon-deforestation/blob/master/src/keras_helper.py#L32 and relevant code from the notebook is:

```
classifier = AmazonKerasClassifier()
classifier.add_conv_layer(img_resize)
classifier.add_flatten_layer()
classifier.add_ann_layer(len(y_map))
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the same *trained* model on those different platforms to factor out potential differences during training ?